# How should I add child element to parent object in react reducer

Tags: react-redux, reducers

I've got a redux parent object that I'm building based on various api calls and used across components. When I receive new api data, I add a nested object to this parent component.

My current method deepClone's the parent object, adds the new child and then calls a reducer to update the store return { ...state, parent_object: action.value };

This works to an extent although mapStateToProps is not being called when the reducer updates. Also, deepCloning the parent object every time doesn't seem to make sense.

Could someone provide some insight into the proper way to do this.

Comment: Why do you add another object? Do you need to keep history of the data? If not, why don't you override the redux object with only the new data? 

If you keep history, what do you use it for? It will reset either way when app unmounts.

Comment: Not really keeping history - adding data sets for data analysis based on user selection so I cannot overwrite the previous version.

Comment: Maybe add first state as a first item of an array into parent object, and every subsequent append as a new array item of the same object. This way you have "history" and you can compare differences between indexes. Also, you can map the array if needed.

Comment: thanks, that is the route I was starting to consider, i.e., instead of this: clone entire object, add array element, send entire object to reducer... do this: create new array element, send new element to reducer and add to parent object. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, and then each array index is a point in history.